# Sniffing in c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I'm trying to sniff packets in CPP using Winsock, but there is a problem.
When I'm creating a socket, it needs to be a "raw socket" so it could be diverted to "sniff mode":
`sniffer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);` but when I create that socket, the program needs to be on an admin mode.

I wanted to know if there is a way to bypass this, or there is another way to sniff packets in CPP without needed an admin mode.
Thanks!

Comment: Privileged execution is unrelated to C++

Comment: I know that execution level dose not related to c++ itself but to create the socket with the windows api it needs to be an admin. I asked if there is another way to sniff packets with windows api or there is another 3rd party library that can do that.

Comment: Bypass root check? Sounds hacky to me

Comment: it for education purpose if you want to know ;)

Answer (score 1):

The operation is privileged and on some platforms it is not available at all. On POSIX platform, user might need to be in certain group, not necessary a root, on Linux you may run `ls -l` against respective device node representing network interface to find out proper user group (it still might be root).

In general you need a packet capturing library that comes with a kernel-space driver\module to actually bypass it. Example of such library is allmighty libpcap, used by Wireshark. There are ports to other systems, including Windows, called WinPCap.

Comment: do you know any library that dose not require an admin for the sniffing?

Comment: @justaman no, it was designed so for security purposes. to install libpcap you would need admin/sudo privileges, but program using that library may run in different context.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "*On Windows , to my knowledge, raw reading from socket is completely impossible*" - now true at all, however [RAW sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2) are restricted to admin users only, as the OP has discovered.

Comment: @RemyLebeau lst time I was porting something to windows, SOCK_RAW wasn't even defined. Apparently it's a late feature of v.2 WinSock now.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie you were likely just using an outdated SDK at the time. RAW sockets have been part of WinSock since 1.1 in Windows 9x/NT4, but were limited to only IGMP and ICMP packets. That limitation was removed around Windows 2000, at the same time that the admin requirement was imposed.

Comment: If only the world didn't have smurfholes. We wouldn't need all this security and things would be much simpler.